# add multiple assets in laravel like multiple style files and script files

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

can i able to add multiple style or script files in single ? 
Normally we add a single style sheet like as follow

```
HTML::style('css/style1.css');
```

for another  style we should

```
 HTML::style('css/style2.css');
```

But i need to use both files or multiple files as asset in laravel.

Comment: you can use it as many times as you need.. btw why is it tagged as both laravel-4 and laravel-3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [Laravel Guard](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-Guard). It's best practice to use concatenated and minified js/css files anyway.

As a bonus, Laravel Guard handles stylesheets and js-files in exactly the way you requested.